# vaadin deploy on tomcat does not work

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat, vaadin, web-deployment

I am building an application with `Vaadin charts`. For test I am inserting hard coded data , but now I am using data from `SQL Server`.

I am building the app on maven and deploying my app on Apache Tomcat. 
While I did not used sql server I did not had any problems. 
Now I am getting error:

> "The origin server did not find a current representation for the
>   target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

I think that I am missing sql server connector.

[image: error image]

Comment: Not a bad question, please put your error code in code, and not as an image.

Comment: Look in the tomcat server + context logs